# How to return value from INSERT statement in transaction block?

Tags: postgresql, temporal-tables

My goal is to return `transaction_start` value.
Tried RETURNING keyword.

But in transaction it is not working. There is no errors in result. The result just contains no data.

Is there other way to achieve this goal?

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM table_for_tests WHERE item_id = '142';
INSERT INTO table_for_tests (item_id, valid, key, value) 
VALUES 
  ('142', tstzrange('1970-01-01T03:00', '1970-01-01T03:00:00.000100', '[)'), 'key1', 'modified value1'), 
  ('142', tstzrange('1970-01-01T03:00', '1970-01-01T03:00:00.000100', '[)'), 'key2', 'modified value2') 
RETURNING lower(transaction) as transaction_start;
COMMIT;
```

**UPD**:

`table_for_tests` schema:

```
id         | item_id  | valid               | transaction        | key           | value 
BIGSERIAL  | BIGINT   | TSTZRANGE NOT NULL  | TSTZRANGE NOT NULL | VARCHAR(255)  | VARCHAR(255)
```

`transaction` column is filled automatically by trigger (posgresql [temporal_tables](https://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/) extension) while executing INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operation.

The trigger was created by this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER versioning_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON 
table_for_tests FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE versioning('transaction', 'table_for_tests_history', true);
```

**UPD 2**:

Source code of the `trigger function (versioning)`, from pgAdmin III:

```
-- Function: public.versioning()

-- DROP FUNCTION public.versioning();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.versioning()
  RETURNS trigger AS
'$libdir/temporal_tables', 'versioning'
  LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 1;
ALTER FUNCTION public.versioning()
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.versioning() TO postgres;
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.versioning() FROM public;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.versioning() IS 'System-period temporal table trigger';
```

Comment: Describe "not working".

Comment: 'Not working' means after executing query in transaction it is not returning value. I tried to return 'id' (primary key) - also not returning value.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the source code of the trigger _function_ (`versioning`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added source code of the trigger function (versioning)  from pgAdmin SQL pane, but can't get inside because it is C-language lib inside ```temporal_tables``` extention.

Comment: Ok, this is not a question about PostgreSQL, but about an extension. You should [ask](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables/issues) the authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem with [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/).

It has `DSLContext` with `transactionResult()` method.

Example:

```
KeyValuesRecord record = context.transactionResult(tx -> {

tx.dsl().deleteFrom(KEY_VALUES)
            .where(KEY_VALUES.ITEM_ID.eq('142'))
            .execute();

KeyValuesRecord insertResult = tx.dsl().insertInto(KEY_VALUES, KEY_VALUES.ITEM_ID, KEY_VALUES.VALID, KEY_VALUES.VALUE)
        .values(itemId, range, value)
        .returning(KEY_VALUES.TRANSACTION)
        .fetchOne(); 

return insertResult;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The RETURNING clause not work at the transaction level, it works on on the row level. A row is returned for each row processed. Further the clause requires what would be a valid select, so * or a column name. Try:

```
 insert into table_for_tests (item_id, valid, key, value) 
       values 
         ('142', tstzrange('1970-01-01t03:00', '1970-01-01T03:00:00.000100', '[)'), 'key1', 'modified value1'), 
         ('142', tstzrange('1970-01-01t03:00', '1970-01-01T03:00:00.000100', '[)'), 'key2', 'modified value2') 
      returning lower(valid) as transaction_start;
```

Or perhaps:

```
with do_ins  as  
     ( insert into table_for_tests (item_id, valid, key, value) 
       values 
         ('142', tstzrange('1970-01-01T03:00', '1970-01-01T03:00:00.000100', '[)'), 'key1', 'modified value1'), 
         ('142', tstzrange('1970-01-01T03:00', '1970-01-01T03:00:00.000100', '[)'), 'key2', 'modified value2') 
      returning lower(valid) as transaction_start
    )
select distinct transaction_start, count(*) over (partition by transaction_start)
  from do_ins;
```

Comment: Could your second variant be executed as part of BEGIN COMMIT block?

Comment: Tried your code in transaction (begin commit). No results were returned by the query.

Comment: You need to post exactly what you are running and a description of how. And since you are contending no results and provide no error message, then best for you to provide [mcve].